# Changed the PATH, now I'm getting "command not found" for everything

Tags: linux, path, amazon-ec2

Amazon Linux Server, connected with SSH:

I tried to change the PATH for the apache user by making some changes in /etc/environment (`PATH=$PATH:/opt/openoffice4/program`)  and /etc/sysconfig/httpd (`export PATH = ${PATH:$PATH:}/opt/openoffice4/program`).

Then I rebooted.

Now, I can not do anything, even `ls -l` leads to `-bash: ls: command not found`

What can I do to regain control?

Comment: Can you run commands directly? For example `/bin/ls`?

Comment: yes, I can run /bin/ls

Comment: Then you should be able to run `/bin/vi` and fix the files where you broke the path.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

#### What can I do to regain control?

Run `/bin/vi` and revert the changes you made to `/etc/environment` and `/etc/sysconfig/httpd` .

Answer (score 31):

You can set your `PATH` without an editor. Just type this in the shell:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:$HOME/bin
```

Comment: And remove the spaces! `PATH=something`, NOT `PATH = something`

Comment: That ought to be quoted, or else `$HOME` will be subject to globbing and word-splitting.  IOW, it will break if `$HOME` has a space in it (plausible) or any glob characters (less likely).

Comment: @Kevin I tried it and the spaces and globs were just copied. (Writing `export PATH=/path to home/bin` doesn't work, of course.)

Comment: @Kevin That's how it behaves in strictly conforming implementations, but at least bash gives `export` custom syntax rules which don't have that problem. (Custom syntax rules were already required for other reasons, e.g. to allow `export array=(1 2 3)`.)

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this would help:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:$HOME/bin
```

The 'export' command isn't used from /usr/bin, so that's why it still works!

Comment: This answer has already been suggested.